# installing R package from source with codes in /src fails in Windows 7

Tags: r, package

I made a package containing /scr folder, and I want to install it in Windows 7. I installed the Rtools for Windows in case any compiler issue, but when I run:

```
> install.packages("mypackage.tar.gz", repos="NULL", type="source")
```

I still get the error message as below:

```
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/UserName/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository NULL/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘mypackage.tar.gz’ is not available (for R version 2.15.1)
```

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252  LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats   graphics  grDevices utils   datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.1
```

Is there anything that is missing for installing R packages from source (with /src) in Windows 7? Thanks!

Comment: try `repos=NULL` (no quotation marks!)

Comment: @BenBolker thanks! I didn't notice that quotes...